# Should I request a CVE for bugs in number-crunching software?

Tags: buffer-overflow, cve

I found several memory bugs in a number-crunching software which I uses daily (for fun) using valgrind and address sanitizer. I have contacted the author and he is now working hard to track down and fix the bug.

Should I request a CVE for it? I am asking because I also maintain it for a distribution.

Should these bugs be considered serious? Usually you don't run the program as root, but the program does not prevent you from doing so either. Should I change the wrapper script so that it drops root privilege and dies if it can't?

Thanks you!

Comment: I presume the app has some kind of file format for input? Would people be likely to take those files from untrusted sources, e.g. email? If so, the vulnerability does matter, and you should request a CVE.

Comment: @paj28 The inputs are taken from a website over http manually. Do you think there is a potential problem?

Comment: So someone could upload input to the website, and use the memory corruption flaw to take control of the web server? Yep, that sounds bad, get a CVE!

Answer (score 1):

If this is truly a vulnerability then yes get a CVE.  But remember, all bugs are not vulnerabilities.  Looking at the previous comments, if an attacker could take over a website or make it crash then yes, that's definitely a vulnerability.

Comment: And not all vulnerabilities are exploitable. ;)

Comment: But most vulnerabilities you (not you specifically, everyone) think are not exploitable actually **are** exploitable.